# Get the h1 tag on current page in PHP

Tags: php

Is it possible to get the h1 title on a page in php while it's being build?
For instance, in a simplified way

```
echo("<html><body><h1>hello</h1><p>some text</p>");
echo ("<p>some more text</p>");
do some more php stuff
Get value of H1 from above?
echo ("</body></html>");
?>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you're echoing the `<h1>` tag, surely you already know what's in it?

Comment: This feels like an XY problem, where you've got a result and your trying to work with it instead of solving a different but related problem earlier. But if this is the path you are going down, I'd look into the output buffer. That will "cache" things from `echo` and you can try to use the regex that hannes_rd posted.

Comment: Where is that `h1` tag coming from in reality? Are you including it from another file?

Answer (score 0):

You can achive it like this:

```
<?php
//assign values
$string_start = "<html><body><h1>hello</h1><p>some text</p>";
$string_more = "<p>some more text</p>";
$string_end = "</body></html>";

//regex
preg_match('~<h1>([^{]*)</h1>~i', $string_start, $match);
$h1 = $match[1];

echo $string_start;
echo $string_start;

//do some more php stuff

//print h1
echo "<p>This h1 is: ".$h1."</p>";

echo $string_end; 
?>
```

Comment: It's part of a wordpress site, so don't have directly access to all the previous generate content on the page from that scope. so the string solution wouldn't work. just tried to make the example simple to show the main issue. I have tried a few different approaches like adding a javascript at the get h1 point, but it didn't have access to the h1 tag either at that point. I guess what I am asking isn't possible.